# How to handle Notification click event in android using OneSignal.com?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, handle, onesignal

I'm new in android. I want to open a new activity when notification click, now it open automatically mainActivity. Code is given below.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView titletv,messagetv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OneSignal.startInit(this).setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler()).init();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        titletv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        messagetv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
    }


    // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it or one is received while the app is running.
    private class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(String message, JSONObject additionalData, boolean isActive) {
            try {
                if (additionalData != null) {
                    if (additionalData.has("actionSelected"))

                        Log.d("OneSignalExample", "OneSignal notification button with id " + additionalData.getString("actionSelected") + " pressed");

                    Log.d("OneSignalExample", "Full additionalData:\n" + additionalData.toString());
                    messagetv.setText(additionalData.toString());
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

Comment: you sent data **actionSelected**  key in OneSignal **Include Additional Data** which is in optional filed in OneSignal panel

Comment: Edited out the Firebase tag and added in OneSignal. Please use significant tags only.